# how to retrieve the request body parameters in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2

Client request url with some POST data. How can I retrieve that variable using CURL?

I have to retrieve that in JSON format variable and do the operation using those variables.

Answer (score -2):

we insert our JSON DATA in REQUEST BODY in this form

{ "firstname":"vijay", "secondname":"bokka", "email":"vijayiiitn@gmail.com" }

as part of api implementation one method will be invoked when api url is trigged.

to that method interface write

apiinvokedmethod($firstname,$secondname,$email)

{

}

you can access value of '$firstname' automatically in the class where you implemented this interface class

NOTE:: The value of KEY in json and name of the METHOD PARAMETERE should be equal